# Calculate average slope over a period of time with python

Tags: python, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I would like to calculate the average slope of multiple numbers. For example:
I've been given 5 numbers (eg. 1.1523, 1.4626, 1.5734, 1.8583, 1.6899). I get a new number every 15 minutes and delete the oldest and want to calculate again the average slope.

I've already seen formulas but I don't really get how to calculate it when like the imaginary x-axis is the time. Like I have:
X: 14:00,  14:15,  14:30,  14:45,  15:00
Y: 1.1523, 1.4626, 1.5734, 1.8583, 1.6899

Comment: not sure what the generally accepted method is for average slope, but I'd think you'd calculate the slope at each point in time you have, then average them. Determine slope between 14:00 and 14:15, slope between 14:15 and 14:30, etc then sum the slopes and divide by 4.

Comment: I think you'll need to decide on what unit you need for x. Minutes might be a place to start. See: https://youtu.be/uX75L8Ea6qo?t=301

Comment: @Erwin109 do neither answers answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all times are in HH:MM format and we don't need to worry about passing midnight, this should work:

```
        X = ['14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00']
        Y = [1.1523, 1.4626, 1.5734, 1.8583, 1.6899]
        minutes = [int(s[:2]) * 60 + int(s[3:]) for s in X]
        slope = (Y[-1] - Y[0]) / ((minutes[-1] - minutes[0]) / 60)
        print(slope)
        slopes = [(Y[i] - Y[i - 1]) / ((minutes[i] - minutes[i - 1]) / 60) for i in range(1, len(X))]
        print(slopes)
        averageSlope = sum(slopes) / (len(X) - 1)
        print(averageSlope)
```

Results:

```
0.5375999999999999
[1.2411999999999992, 0.44320000000000004, 1.1396000000000006, -0.6736000000000004]
0.5375999999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but isn't average slope determined the same way as average velocity - which is Delta d / Delta t? If that is the case, shouldn't it be Delta Y / Delta X?

```
from datetime import datetime

X = ['14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00']
Y = [1.1523, 1.4626, 1.5734, 1.8583, 1.6899]
today = datetime.now()
avg = []

for i in range(len(X) - 1):
    e = X[i + 1].split(":")
    e = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, int(e[0]), int(e[1]))
    s = X[i].split(":")
    s = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, int(s[0]), int(s[1]))
    deltaX = e - s
    deltaY = Y[i + 1] - Y[i]
    ans = (deltaY / deltaX.seconds) / 60
    avg.append(f'{ans:.9f}')

print(avg)
```

```
['0.000005746', '0.000002052', '0.000005276', '-0.000003119']
```

---

Consider this data:

```
1 minute(s) 1 meter(s)
2 minute(s) 2 meter(s)
3 minute(s) 3 meter(s)
```

You should have a slope of 1 meter/minute, no matter how you cut the cake.

Likewise for this:

```
1 minute(s) 2 meter(s)
2 minute(s) 3 meter(s)
3 minute(s) 5 meter(s)
```

From 2 to 1 minutes, the average is 1 meters/minute, from 3 to 2 minutes its 2 meters/minute, and from 3 to 1 minutes its 1.5 meters/minute.